# Private ArrayList shared by all members in class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, private

When I use the setAssetWeight method to set values of objects stored in the ArrayList, every instance of the object has the values in their ArrayLists changed to the value set with setAssetWeight.

```
private List<Asset> assetList = new ArrayList<Asset>();
private int fitness;

public Portfolio(){    
}

public void setAssetWeight(int i, int weight){
    this.assetList.get(i).setWeight(weight);
}
```

For example: If i create two Portfolio objects, pf1 and pf2, then do

```
pf1.setAssetWeight(0, 10);
```

When I print the weight of the assets contained in pf2, it will show the first asset as having a weighting of 10, rather than the default 0.

Why are the values in the ArrayList of one instance of the object being changed when i call the method using the other object? The ArrayList is declared as private, shouldn't this mean that it can only be modified by the object it belongs to?

```
Portfolio1 pf1 = new Portfolio1();
Portfolio1 pf2 = new Portfolio1();

pf1.add(0, assetList.get(0));
pf1.add(1, assetList.get(1));
pf1.add(2, assetList.get(2));

pf1.setAssetWeight(0, 10);

System.out.println(pf2.toString());
```

This is the section of code I am using to test, in this example, the print statement will print out that the first asset in AssetList has a weighting of 10, even though I only set the weighting for pf1, not pf2.

```
public void add(Asset asset){
    this.assetList.add(asset);
}
```

This is the code used to add assets to the list.

Comment: what is your question? This is just a bunch of statements.

Comment: Edited to include my question, sorry about that

Comment: Post your full code, including print statements

Comment: Please post also the code that creates and adds elements to those lists. My guess is that you are using the same `Asset` elements in both lists. Even if the lists are different, if the same element is contained in both, the change will be reflected in all the occurrences.

Comment: The assetList used contains different Assets, but for each Portfolio, the assets are all the same, the only difference should be the weighting of each asset, when I change the weighting of an asset for one portfolio, the weighting of the asset changes in every portfolio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cannot reproduce. You are undoubtedly adding the same Asset instance into the List<Asset> in both instances.